# Spyder ide just give me solution of this program but python idle just not proceed after print array

Tags: python, spyder

```
a=[]

n=int(input('how many element you enter'))

for i in range(0,n):
    x=int(input('enter'))
    a.append(x)
print (a)    

for i in range(0,n-1):
    for j in range(i,n-1):
        if a[i]==abs(a[j+1]):
            print ('',a[i],a[j+1])
```

Comment: do you know that your program is looking for same elements in array so give appropriate input and you will be good to go

Comment: please improve your question's title, its quite confusing

Comment: for i in range(0,n-1):
    for j in range(i,n-1):
        if a[i]==abs(a[j+1]):
            print ('',a[i],a[j+1])    This part is not proceed in python idle but the whole code run properly in spyder-Anaconda idle......